# Multiple background images, appending images

Tags: css

Is there anyway in CSS to have background image "appended" as an additional background image to a DIV rather than "setting" it as a value (i.e. replacing the already existing one).

Jamil

Comment: Can you not just put another div below the existing div and give that the "appended" part of the image using its own css background?

Comment: I am exactly trying to avoid that @Wes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really doing that and not setting them on pseudo-elements ([**DEMO**](http://dabblet.com/gist/3621981))/ children/ of the element having the same size and stacked on top of the element?

**NO**.

Same thing goes for `box-shadow`, `transition` & others. It is possible that things will change in the future (see [**this article**](http://www.xanthir.com/blog/#4KZ0)), but for now... the answer to this question is still no.

Comment: That's brilliant @Ana , Pseudo-elements is what I was missing !

Answer (score 0):

I might be understanding your question wrongly (refer to Ana's answer if so), but you can use multiple images as a `background` to the same element by separating their specifiers with a comma:

```
background: url("background1.png"), url("background2.png"), ...;
```

You can specify properties for each one separately just like you would do in shorthand normally:

```
background: url("background1.png") no-repeat 50% 50%, url("background2.png"), ...;
```